# Why doesn't storybook work with checkbox?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

The problem is my component checkbox does not see types that are written in my component.

The component that I want to test is below.

```
interface IProps {
  name?: string;
  className?: string;
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
  label?: string;
  color?: 'primary' | 'success' | 'secondary' | 'danger' | 'warning' | 'info' | 'dark';
  value?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  checked?: boolean;
  onChange?: (event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  indeterminate?: boolean;
}
type DefaultProps = Partial<IProps>;
const defaultProps: DefaultProps = {
  color: 'primary',
  disabled: false,
  label: '',
};
const Checkbox: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {

  const [isChecked, setChecked] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const {label, color, name, value, indeterminate, onChange, checked, disabled, ...nextProps} = props;
  const cRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cRef?.current && indeterminate) {
      cRef.current.indeterminate = true;
    }
  }, [indeterminate, cRef]);

  const handleClick = (event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(event);
    }
    setChecked(!isChecked);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label
        className={classNames(
          'checkbox',
          `checkbox-${color}`
        )}
      >
        <input
          {...nextProps}
          type="checkbox"
          checked={checked || isChecked}
          onChange={handleClick}
          disabled={disabled}
          ref={cRef}
        />
        <span>{label}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

It is storybook with my component checkbox.

```
export default {
  title: 'Example/CheckBox',
  component: CheckBox,
} as ComponentMeta<typeof CheckBox>;

const Template: ComponentStory<typeof CheckBox> = (args) => <CheckBox {...args} />;

export const Primary = Template.bind({});
Primary.args = {
  color: 'secondary',
  indeterminate: true
};
```

If I put the same code in component Button, there are no problems and I can change whatever I want.

Example:
It is checkbox, that does not work
[image]

It is component button, that has almost the same code, but it works properly.

[image]

Actually, I dont have any idea why it happens so. What's wrong with my checkbox?

Comment: Please remove the code-photos and past in the text instead.

Comment: Done. Check, please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storybook does not show props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73853062/storybook-does-not-show-props)

Comment: Please stop posting identical questions (this is the third) just because they’re not receiving answers: look at how you can improve the chances of receiving help, see [mcve]

Comment: No, unfortunately, I am looking for answer for several days. But out of success. Dont have any idea where to find explanation to behaviour of components in storybook

Answer (score 0):

Check the title field in the export default of your Checkbox story. It’s the same like button it should be unique.
[image]

Comment: I've corrected that. But the same problem, checkbox does not see types. I added all code above in post.

Comment: Does the checkbox appears in your storybook sidebar menu at all? Please post both story files for button and checkbox.

Comment: It appears, but there are no parameters which i can change such as color, checked, indeterminate and so on.